# Get/Set BigQuery Job ID while doing BigQueryIO.write()

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to set BigQuery JobID or to get it while the batch pipeline is running.
I know it's possible using BigQuery API but is it possible if I'm using BigQueryIO from Apache Beam? 
I need to send an acknowledgement after writing to BigQuery that the load is complete.

Answer (score 5):

Currently this is not possible. It is complicated by the fact that a single `BigQueryIO.write()` may use many BigQuery jobs under the hood (i.e. `BigQueryIO.write()` is a general-purpose API for writing data to BigQuery, rather than an API for working with a single specific BigQuery load job), e.g.:

- In case the amount of data to be loaded is larger than the BigQuery limits for a single load job, `BigQueryIO.write()` will shard it into multiple load jobs.
- In case you are using one of the destination-dependent write methods (e.g. `DynamicDestinations`), and are loading into multiple tables at the same time, there'll be at least 1 load job per table.
- In case you are writing an unbounded `PCollection` using the `BATCH_LOADS` method, it will periodically issue load jobs for newly arrived data, subject to the notes above.
- In case you're using the `STREAMING_INSERTS` method (it is allowed to use it even if you're writing a bounded `PCollection`), there will be no load jobs at all.

You will need to use one of the typical workarounds for "doing something after something else is done", which is, e.g. wait until the entire pipeline is done using `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()` in your main program and then do your second action.

Comment: Very cool answer! Just wondering if you could tell us where the writing in shards happens in the code. Is it the `apitools` library that already handles that or is it `BigQuerySink` class? I was trying to find where it happens in the code but couldn't find it yet :)

Comment: @jkff Okay. But will the workaround that you suggested work in case of templates because as per my understanding any statement written after pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish() will not be a part of my template. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately there's no good solution for this with templates currently.